# ORA-01425 (escape character must be character string of length 1) but only when using COUNT and OR connections in the where clause

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, odata

The Entity Framework (6.1.3.) generates LIKE statements with ESCAPE '\' in case I have a startswith, contains etc. queuery. Only when using COUNT and connecting the criteria with OR I get an ORA-01425.

Everything is generated: DevExpress CriteriaOperator -> Microsoft ODataClient -> Server -> Entity Framework -> Oracle ManagedDataAccess.

It is suggested to use .Trim() to avoid the ESCAPE at all. However, everything is generated.

In case my criteria in the WHERE clause is connected by AND everything works.

```
SELECT 
"GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1"
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS "A1"
    FROM   (SELECT "Extent1"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL" AS "PRIMARSCHLUSSEL1", ...
        FROM  "SCHEMATABLE"."SCHEMATABLE_WORKFLOW" "Extent1"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SCHEMATABLE"."SCHEMATABLE_FFB" "Extent2" ON ("Extent1"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL" = "Extent2"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL") AND (("Extent2"."GELOSCHT" = :DynamicFilterParam_000001) )
        WHERE ("Extent1"."GELOSCHT" <> 1) ) "Filter1"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "SCHEMATABLE"."SCHEMATABLE_FFB" "Extent3" ON (("Extent3"."GELOSCHT" = :DynamicFilterParam_000001) ) AND ("Filter1"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL1" = "Extent3"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL")
    WHERE ((("Filter1"."GELOSCHT1" = :DynamicFilterParam_000001) ) AND ("Filter1"."ART" LIKE :p__linq__0 ESCAPE '\') AND ("Filter1"."GRUPPE" LIKE :p__linq__1 ESCAPE '\') AND ("Extent3"."EINKAUFER" LIKE :p__linq__2 ESCAPE '\'))
)  "GroupBy1"
```

If I change it to OR I get the ORA-01425.

```
SELECT 
"GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1"
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS "A1"
    FROM   (SELECT "Extent1"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL" AS "PRIMARSCHLUSSEL1", ...
        FROM  "SCHEMATABLE"."SCHEMATABLE_WORKFLOW" "Extent1"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "SCHEMATABLE"."SCHEMATABLE_FFB" "Extent2" ON ("Extent1"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL" = "Extent2"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL") AND (("Extent2"."GELOSCHT" = :DynamicFilterParam_000001) )
        WHERE ("Extent1"."GELOSCHT" <> 1) ) "Filter1"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "SCHEMATABLE"."SCHEMATABLE_FFB" "Extent3" ON (("Extent3"."GELOSCHT" = :DynamicFilterParam_000001) ) AND ("Filter1"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL1" = "Extent3"."PRIMARSCHLUSSEL")
    WHERE ((("Filter1"."GELOSCHT1" = :DynamicFilterParam_000001) ) AND (("Filter1"."ART" LIKE :p__linq__0 ESCAPE '\') OR ("Filter1"."GRUPPE" LIKE :p__linq__1 ESCAPE '\') OR ("Extent3"."EINKAUFER" LIKE :p__linq__2 ESCAPE '\')))
)  "GroupBy1"
```

```
-- DynamicFilterParam_000001: '0' (Type = Decimal, IsNullable = false)

-- DynamicFilterParam_000002: 'null' (Type = Decimal)

-- p__linq__0: 'T%' (Type = Object)

-- p__linq__1: 'K%' (Type = Object)

-- p__linq__2: '%e%' (Type = Object)
```

By the way, this statement works for me too:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FFB WHERE ((geloscht = 0) AND ((ART LIKE 'T%' ESCAPE '\') OR (GRUPPE LIKE 'K%' ESCAPE '\') OR (EINKAUFER LIKE '%e%' ESCAPE '\')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering at the hands of Oracle bug 28642551 (**"ORA-1425 FROM CORRECT QUERY INCLUDING OR OPERATION"**).

The good news is that it is fixed in Oracle version 20.1. Ha ha. The better news is that there is a patch for it in 12.2. Have your DBAs check Oracle's support web site.

If that's not an option, you might workaround it by having your Entity Framework not try to use `NVARCHAR2` for its bind variables.